# ¿Cómo hacer correctamente 3 eventos de mouse en el mismo SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

estoy intentando crear un juego de unir con líneas utilizando **SVG**, las cuales tienen 2 columnas, y debo unir correctamente ambas, lo que quiero hacer es que con el evento *mousedown* sobre los gráficos de la primera columna dibuje una linea que siga el mouse (lo logre con js, pero acceder al DOM de svg con js puro se me es imposible), luego con el evento *mousemove* envió puntos finales (x2 y y2) para que la linea "sigan al mouse" (si lo logro) el problema es al llega al otro grafico el destino, no me funciona el evento *mouseup* para que se "detenga" el evento *mousemove* (mi especulación es que el *mousemove* lo estoy haciendo en el svg completo y ya ignora el otro elemento al estar dentro del mismo).
Los g (que son los graficos) tiene una clase llamada objetos (la primera columna tienen clase "numeros" y la segunda columna clase "objetivo", el svg tiene un id llamado entorno, los jQuery quedarían algo así:

```
var pressing = false;
(document).ready(function() {
    $('body #entorno .objetos').on('mousedown', '.numeros', function(e) {
        pressing = true;
//un codigo que permite enviarle parámetros iniciales de x y y de una linea svg
    })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body #entorno .objetos').on('mouseup', '.objetivo', function stop(e) {
        pressing = false;
//un código que permite enviarle desaparecer la linea inicial y crear una linea dependiendo si esta
//correcta la primera y segunda columna de gráficos 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body ').on('mousemove', '#entorno ', function move(e) {
        if (pressing) { //valida que sea true para que se ejecute
           //una función que permite seguir la linea con el mouse
        }
    })
})
```

el codigo html es algo como esto (no es exactamente así, pero para simplificar y quede mas entendible)

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000" id="entorno">
        <g class="objetos"><image id="1" class="numeros"  xlink:href="../img/UNIR CON LINEAS/1.png" ></g> 
          <g class="objetos"  ><image  id="8" class="objetivo" xlink:href="../img/UNIR CON LINEAS/8.png" ></g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: No encontré la solución, pero mi hipótesis es que no funciona porque el evento "mousemove" lo aplico para el svg en general (el "entorno") y las imágenes las tengo dentro del la etiqueta g, pero como el orden de las imagenes las genero aleatoriamente se me complica obtener el id y las posiciones, mi solucion fue no usar el evento mousemove y aplicar 2 clicks para unir con linea.

Answer (score 2):

En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo círculos para números y rectángulos para objetivos porque me pareció más claro. Tu puedes utilizar imágenes y grupos si quieres.

Asimismo el elemento svg tiene un atributo viewBox y es responsive. Tu si prefieres puedes utilizar los atributos width y height.

1. si haces mousedown encima de un circulo (número) el programa crea una nueva línea que sale del centro del circulo y acaba donde el ratón
2. Al mover el ratón encima del lienzo svg la línea cambia la posición y acaba donde el ratón.
3. Al hacer mouseup encima de un rectángulo la línea acaba en el centro de este. Si haces mouseup fuera de uno de los rectángulos el programa borra la última línea.

Por favor lea los comentarios en el código:

```js
//el espacio de nombre utilizado para crear una nueva línea
const SVG_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
//el elemento svg
const svg = document.querySelector("#entorno");
//todos los números representados por circulos
let circulos = document.querySelectorAll(".numeros");
//todos los objetivos representados por rectangulos
let rects = document.querySelectorAll(".objetivo");
//dos booleanos para saber si
// el mousedown pasa encima de un circulo
let pressing = false;
// el mouseup pasa encima de un rectangulo
let rectUp = false;
let line;


//para cada circulo (número)
circulos.forEach((c) => {
  //al hacer moudedown
  c.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { 
  //establece el valor de pressing y rectUp
    pressing = true;
    rectUp = false;
    //crea una nueva línea empiezando (x1,y1) y acabando (x2,y2) en el crntro del circulo
    let o = {};
    (o.x1 = c.getAttribute("cx")), (o.x2 = o.x1);
    (o.y1 = c.getAttribute("cy")), (o.y2 = o.y1);
    line = drawSVGelmt(o, "line", svg);
  });
});

rects.forEach((r) => {
  //si al hacer mouseup estoy encima de un rectangulo (objetivo) establece el x2 e y2 de la línea como el centro del rectángulo
  r.addEventListener("mouseup", (e) => {
    pressing = false;
    rectUp = true;
    line.setAttribute("x2", Number(r.getAttribute("x")) + 10);
    line.setAttribute("y2", Number(r.getAttribute("y")) + 10);
  });
});

svg.addEventListener("mousemove", (evento) => {
//al hacer mousemove encima del svg establece el x2 e y2 de la línea igual a la posición del ratón 
  if (pressing) {
    //la posición del ratón
    let pos = oMousePosSVG(evento);
    //establece el x2 e y2 de la línea
    line.setAttribute("x2", pos.x);
    line.setAttribute("y2", pos.y);
  }
});

svg.addEventListener("mouseup", (evento) => {
//si al hacer mouseup NO estoy encima de un rectangulo (objetivo) elimina la última línea dibujada
  if (!rectUp) {
    svg.removeChild(svg.lastChild);
  }
});


//una función para establecer la posición del ratón encima de un elemento svg
function oMousePosSVG(evento) {
  var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
  p.x = evento.clientX;
  p.y = evento.clientY;
  var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
  var p = p.matrixTransform(ctm);
  return p;
}


//una función para cerar un nuevo elemento svg utilizada para crear una nueva línea
function drawSVGelmt(o, tag, parent) {
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
line{stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 350" id="entorno">
  <g class="objetos">
    <circle id="c1" class="numeros" r="10" cx="100" cy="100" />
    <circle id="c2" class="numeros" r="10" cx="100" cy="200" />
  </g>
  <g class="objetos">
    <rect id="r7" class="objetivo" x="910" y="160" width="20" height="20" />
    <rect id="r8" class="objetivo" x="910" y="260" width="20" height="20" />
  </g>
</svg>
```